# Ejecutar evento OnClick con Razor Pages

Tags: razor, cshtml

Tengo una página de Razor (.cshtml) en la cual se encuentra un input que me gustaría que disparara un evento cada vez que se ha escrito algo en él. Ese evento sería llamar a una función que está alojada en el fichero .cs de la página. El código que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
@page

@using Components

@model IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<!-- SEARCH FORM -->
<div id="search_form" class="uk-container">
    <header>
        <h1 class="uk-text-center">Escriba un verbo</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="form-container">
        <span class="input-container">
            <input type="text" name="verb" id="form_verb" value="@Model.verb" onchange="@{Model.OnSearchTextChanged()}"/>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pero en este caso, cuando ejecuto el proyecto la página deja de cargar en cuanto trata de cargar el input. Imagino que es porque no es la forma de hacerlo. En cualquier caso, necesitaría sabes cómo llamar a un método de un fichero .cs desde un evento en una página .cshtml

Si puede ayudar en algo, el código del .cs es el siguiente:

```
        [BindProperty]
        public string verb { get; set; }

        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            verb = "";
        }

        public void OnSearchTextChanged()
        {
            _reconocimientos = lematizadorService.GetReconocimientosAsync(verb).Result;
        }
```

Comment: Eso que quieres hacer funciona  solo con aspx. Si estás usando razor tienes que manejar los eventos con javascript y si necesitas datos del servidor hacer una petición ajax al controlador.

Comment: Hay algún ejemplo que pueda seguir entonces para hacerlo? La verdad es que ando un poco perdido. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si vas a seguir con razor puedes buscar algún tutorial de cómo crear un CRUD con asp.NET MVC para que te hagas una idea de como funciona.